# Graphite how to have a cumulative graph

Tags: graphite

I am a beginner with graphite. 
I would like from a graph to have the duration of state (here the state 0):

My original graph:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWPxK.png)

This graph represent the series: 1101000111.
Here one bit during 10 seconds.

The number 1 represent OK.
The number 0 represent Critical.
My goal: it's to represent on other graph the total duration of 0 (the duration of critical state) on a period. The result should be 40seconds because there are four 0 and each 0 during 10seconds , so 4*10=40

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbdZq.png)

My question is: Which function use to have the total duration of 0 represent by a bar with 40second of height?

Thx,

Comment: I did the function summarize. Me, I would like to have the total duration of 0 on a defined period of time.(the result should be 40seconds on the period on this graph). there are too functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
integral(absolute(offset(metricname, -1))
```